# Navier Stokes example not running

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

This may be a pretty noob question, but for some reason, I can't get the following Navier-Stokes FEM example to run

https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/nonlinear-finite-elements/transient-navier-stokes.html?product=mathematica

I am running version 13.1. Everything is copied and pasted from the website...

What is the issue?

[image]

Comment: It's running perfectly. Copy the cells simply by a mouse click to the clipboard (there is a tooltip) and paste then via Ctrl+V to a notebook. Some cells have to be opened by clicking the + first

Comment: It would help a lot if you could post what you ran and where it stopped working, so people know exactly what went wrong on your end and therefore how to help you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi Guys, apologies for the poor post. I have attached an image of the error that I am getting. Please note that the code is the same as the one of the website. I have copied and pasted it. Note that I am also running Mathematica from a Raspberry Pi, not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: You'd need to show all of you code (not as an image but as actual code) the message says that the boundary con gition could not be applied and one would have to look at the (discretization) of the region which you do not show.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get hold of the Mathematica support, it seems that there is an issue with regard to Mathematica on the Raspberry Pi, thus I am getting the resulting error.

They are currently looking into the issue.